# What is maximum possible length of a URL?

Tags: http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum length of an url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url)

What is max number of Query Arguments supported in the GET Request
and in total how long can this GET request be?

Similarly for POST Requests.

Finally,
Good resources for Base64Encoding and Multi-part Form Post requests would be great.

-Ajay

Comment: AFAIK this isn't defined. I think IE6 had a max of 2048 characters for a GET request length.

Comment: You might want to focus on what it is you're trying to achieve after learning this. As Martin points out, this isn't really defined. Why do you want to know this, anyway?

Answer (score 3):

[HTTP 1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) specifies

> The HTTP protocol does not place
>   any a priori limit on the length of
>   a URI. Servers MUST be able to handle
>   the URI of any resource they    serve,
>   and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of
>   unbounded length if they    provide
>   GET-based forms that could generate
>   such URIs. A server    SHOULD return
>   414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a
>   URI is longer    than the server can
>   handle (see section 10.4.15).
>
> ```
>   Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI
>   lengths above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>   implementations might not properly support these lengths.
> ```

No restriction on Content-Length (for POST requests) is specified.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is limited to 2083 characters in the URL: [support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/)
All other browsers have a higher limit as far as I know, but you should keep safely below the smallest limit found.

The limit of a POST request is how large a request the server will allow, one common limitation (found in most Window servers) is 4 MB.